# Matching Chinese character length in regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

I'm trying to perform an input check in php for name tag, which consists of English, Chinese, and numbers.

```
"/^[A-z0-9\p{Han}]{2,12}$/u";
```

I would like to achieve the name tag rule of 12 units of character where a Chinese character is 2 unit and English/Number is 1 unit.

Can a regular expression match for such rule?

To give you some example:

```
六 matches because as of \p{Han} and 2 units
六1 matches because of 0-9, \p{Han}, and 3 units
1 does not match as of 1 unit
一二三四五六七 does not match as of 14 units
```

Comment: It is best to combine the regex with a bit of code. Count all Chinese chars, count all ASCII letter/digits, and calculate the "unit" length. Note [you should not use `[A-z]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926), use `[A-Za-z]`.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering, I have a solution

```
"/^([A-Za-z0-9]{2}|\p{Han})([A-Za-z0-9]{1,2}|\p{Han}){0,5}$/u";
```

The first part `([A-Za-z0-9]{2}|\p{Han})` matches 2 units, either 1 Chinese character or 2 Eng/Num.

immediacy follow by `([A-Za-z0-9]{1,2}|\p{Han}){0,5}` that matches 0 unit to 5 Chinese character or 10 Eng/Num character. Total of 12 units.

Thanks for the note of [Should not use [A-z]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/)

Comment: So, is [`1三23二五七`](https://regex101.com/r/pOLvvE/1) invalid? Its unit length is 11.